# Share model and repositories between spring-boot projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have several spring-boot applications (which will run into several different docker containers), for simplicity let's call them projA and projB. Each of those is structured with the following two main modules:

projA(pom):

- projA-be (jar)
- projA-model (jar) (this also contains the application.yml file)
- other irrilevant modules

same thing for projB.

The -be modules import into their pom the -model module and everything works fine.

Now I need to be able to use the projB model and repositories on projA, what I first thought was, let's brutally import projB-model into projA-be and see what happens, maybe it will work (somehow idk), and yes, it did not work.

Those projects manage completely different things, the objects I'd love to have in common are, obviously, users and accounts.

Is there any way to achieve what above mentioned without having to manually configure the datasources in every project (and thus duplicate a lot of code)?

Or is it there any smarter way to achieve what I was aiming to do (connect to the same database and use the same model objects and repositories)?

Sorry if the question looks a little bit twisted, but ask anything you think could clarify the situation.

Comment: You can put the stuff that is common in a separate project which builds a jar-file. This jar-file can you add as a depencency for both projA and projB.

Comment: @KajHejer in the end there would be no difference because the model of the project is imported just as if it was some module (external or internal), I think that there would be the same problems with the configuration, since each project also has a database of its own in addition to the one I would like to import

Comment: Would you mind elaborating what it is that doesn't work? Maybe your `@EntityScan` or `@EnableJpaRepositories` just doesn't scan the packages of that other JAR?

Comment: In the @EnableJpaRepositories I've put the package of the other jar also, but it seems like it doesn't set correctly the connection with the database properly. Could the problem be the fact I'm trying to use the database described in the application property inside the other jar I'm trying to import?